# WebSocket client in PHP?

Tags: php, websocket

Is there a library or client for connecting to a WebSocket server from PHP? If not, is there a reason why?

([phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) only seem to have Javascript client code.)

Comment: I also needed a PHP Websocket Client and did not find one, so I made my own little PHP-Class. Hopefully it will help you: Github: https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket Blog Post (German): http://lemmingzshadow.net/379/php-websocket-client/

Answer (score 27):

None of the above is a good answer. Several of them are about a server, whereas the question is about a client. The code from Rodislav didn't work for me, as it didn't talk to my WebSockets server on Heroku. However, this library worked very well:

https://github.com/Devristo/phpws

UPDATE: While this code worked when all was well, there seems to be no error returns or exceptions at all, and as a result it's unusable when there's an error (e.g., the server isn't running, the address is wrong, the port is blocked, etc.). So, while it was fun to experiment with, it's not usable in production code.

Comment: Correct: the question is about using a php server as a client to another server, not how to write a php websocket server.

Comment: sorry can't answer because it's closed but, you could try: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl but make sure you mentioned it was built for a book credit where credit it due and all that https://www.packtpub.com/gb/web-development/php-reactive-programming (I'm not the author of this book, i just found the book that lead me to the repo)

Answer (score 14):

well, it's easy and you can do in this 
Thanks to all sources where we found answers *(sorry, I can't remember all)*

```
<?php
$host = '10.9.8.173';  //where is the websocket server
$port = 8575;
$local = "http://mypc";  //url where this script run
$data = "first message";  //data to be send

$head = "GET / HTTP/1.1"."\r\n".
        "Upgrade: WebSocket"."\r\n".
        "Connection: Upgrade"."\r\n".
        "Origin: $local"."\r\n".
        "Host: $host"."\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Key: asdasdaas76da7sd6asd6as7d"."\r\n".
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n"."\r\n";
//WebSocket handshake
$sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
fwrite($sock, $head ) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$headers = fread($sock, 2000);
echo $headers;
fwrite($sock, hybi10Encode($data)) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$wsdata = fread($sock, 2000);
var_dump(hybi10Decode($wsdata));
fclose($sock);


function hybi10Decode($data)
{
    $bytes = $data;
    $dataLength = '';
    $mask = '';
    $coded_data = '';
    $decodedData = '';
    $secondByte = sprintf('%08b', ord($bytes[1]));
    $masked = ($secondByte[0] == '1') ? true : false;
    $dataLength = ($masked === true) ? ord($bytes[1]) & 127 : ord($bytes[1]);

    if($masked === true)
    {
        if($dataLength === 126)
        {
           $mask = substr($bytes, 4, 4);
           $coded_data = substr($bytes, 8);
        }
        elseif($dataLength === 127)
        {
            $mask = substr($bytes, 10, 4);
            $coded_data = substr($bytes, 14);
        }
        else
        {
            $mask = substr($bytes, 2, 4);       
            $coded_data = substr($bytes, 6);        
        }   
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($coded_data); $i++)
        {       
            $decodedData .= $coded_data[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($dataLength === 126)
        {          
           $decodedData = substr($bytes, 4);
        }
        elseif($dataLength === 127)
        {           
            $decodedData = substr($bytes, 10);
        }
        else
        {               
            $decodedData = substr($bytes, 2);       
        }       
    }   

    return $decodedData;
}


function hybi10Encode($payload, $type = 'text', $masked = true) {
    $frameHead = array();
    $frame = '';
    $payloadLength = strlen($payload);

    switch ($type) {
        case 'text':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Text-Frame (10000001):
            $frameHead[0] = 129;
            break;

        case 'close':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Close Frame(10001000):
            $frameHead[0] = 136;
            break;

        case 'ping':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Ping frame (10001001):
            $frameHead[0] = 137;
            break;

        case 'pong':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Pong frame (10001010):
            $frameHead[0] = 138;
            break;
    }

    // set mask and payload length (using 1, 3 or 9 bytes)
    if ($payloadLength > 65535) {
        $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%064b', $payloadLength), 8);
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 255 : 127;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $frameHead[$i + 2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[$i]);
        }

        // most significant bit MUST be 0 (close connection if frame too big)
        if ($frameHead[2] > 127) {
            $this->close(1004);
            return false;
        }
    } elseif ($payloadLength > 125) {
        $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%016b', $payloadLength), 8);
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 254 : 126;
        $frameHead[2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[0]);
        $frameHead[3] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[1]);
    } else {
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
    }

    // convert frame-head to string:
    foreach (array_keys($frameHead) as $i) {
        $frameHead[$i] = chr($frameHead[$i]);
    }

    if ($masked === true) {
        // generate a random mask:
        $mask = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $mask[$i] = chr(rand(0, 255));
        }

        $frameHead = array_merge($frameHead, $mask);
    }
    $frame = implode('', $frameHead);
    // append payload to frame:
    for ($i = 0; $i < $payloadLength; $i++) {
        $frame .= ($masked === true) ? $payload[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4] : $payload[$i];
    }

    return $frame;
}

?>
```

Comment: This answer is out of date.  Many servers require the `Sec-WebSocket-Version` header in the handshake.

Comment: This answer also only works for one-off packets.  For whole streams, the `fread` may eat into the next packet

Comment: based on this post: https://gist.github.com/ZiTAL/40bb7bafad693dc99c5c

Comment: Does this still work then?

Comment: This works as of 2019: https://github.com/paragi/PHP-websocket-client

Comment: It works as of 2022 with little editing.
Just add "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13"."\r\n" to the header.

Comment: This answer works well if you add the Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13 to headers. Just note that to use with websockify (or any other websocket service that only expects binary data), you will need to add binary data type to hybi10Encode, and set $frameHead[0] = 130;

Answer (score 5):

I tried to use many of the above to include in tivoka (json-rpc), but they either wasn't good enough reading larger packets (not getting the whole frame or reading into the next one) or had large dependencies.

So, I wrote https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php

Instead of first reading all available data from the socket and then decoding it, it reads the frame header and parses payload length, and then loads just that.

It lacks ping/pong support, but I think it does most of the other stuff well.  It works well with tivoka and is at least 92% autotested :)   It might need some extra functions to check if there is another frame without actually reading it.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: thank you! Works great.. and very straight forward to use and install. One suggestion is that in the example section you should specify that the send() method is often used for 'subscribe' commands, not to send 'hello world' :) Other than that, great job!

Answer (score 1):

This library looks pretty good, if you're ok with the dependencies: https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-websocket-client

Comment: It looks like this just a WebSocket Server with the wrong name.

Answer (score -1):

A PHP Websocket library with an example chat application. With demo and full description of implementation.

http://www.techzonemind.com/php-websocket-library-two-way-real-time-communication/

Comment: Unfortunately that domain name expired...

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn, the link is updated, it is available now.

Comment: This is an example to create a php websocket server, but the question is how to create a client in php to send data to other (Remote/Local) websocket.

Comment: Seems like time changes everything, this libary does not work anymore, I assume it used too, the Demo page that are provided confirms this (tested in Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Sorry for inactive demo, ws service was gone inactive, activated now.