# sending messages to a tornado websocket server via php?

Tags: php, websocket, tornado

I'm running a tornado websocket server and I need to use php to send a message to it. Is this possible and if so, how do I do it? Everything I'm finding through search is about setting up a php websocket server, but I already have it set up in python...I just need to use php to communicate with it.

Comment: This question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160899/websocket-client-in-php)

Comment: OK, thanks. Here's a follow-up...not sure if I should start a new question. I'm getting this error when I try to connect:

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ws://imaccontrolpanel.nyhq.nytint.com:8080 (Unable to find the socket transport "ws" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fsockopen("imaccontrolpanel.nyhq.nytint.com",8080);