# Outgoing websocket in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to create a bot script for a third party chat service using PHP. The client-server communication is based on socket.io, but works best with websockets - and, in fact, is quite easy to replicate without socket.io in browsers that support websockets. Unlike Javascript, however, PHP can't simply use `new Websocket('ws://host')` and be connected. I've looked at PHP's raw(?) sockets such as [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) and [`socket_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php), but I don't know what to use - `socket_create` comes with the luxury of [`socket_select`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php), but I don't know how to use a socket of that type to target anything other than an IP address - in Javascript, the url the websocket connects to includes the session id. `fsockopen`, on the other hand, can connect to a url this way, but I can't find any functions for waiting until the socket has bytes available to read. Every chat room requires a new socket (and session id), due to limitations of the service, so I need to be able to have multiple sockets all listening at the same time. What's the best direction to approach this from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebSocket client in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160899/websocket-client-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the PHP manual isn't very explicit - you can connect to a url with `socket_connect`, it doesn't have to be an IP address. It'll be annoying to implement the entire websocket protocol by hand - but it is at least functional.