# Connecting by php to a python websocket server

Tags: php, python, websocket, tornado

I have a working websocket Server (python + Tornado) which accepts Connections on port 8973. I can connect by a easy JavaScript / jquery instruction like:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.41.170:8973/rt");
```

But I need my php script to connect to this websocket server and send a message. I tried all most available solutions like

https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket/

```
$host = '192.168.41.170';  //where is the websocket server
$port = 8973;
$local = "http://192.168.41.2/";  //url where this script run
$data = 'hello world!';  //data to be send

$head = "GET / HTTP/1.1"."\r\n".
        "Upgrade: WebSocket"."\r\n".
        "Connection: Upgrade"."\r\n".
        "Origin: $local"."\r\n".
        "Host: $host"."\r\n".
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n"."\r\n";
//WebSocket handshake
$sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
fwrite($sock, $head ) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$headers = fread($sock, 2000);
fwrite($sock, "\x00$data\xff" ) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$wsdata = fread($sock, 2000);  //receives the data included in the websocket     package "\x00DATA\xff"
fclose($sock);
```

But this all dont work. Has anybody a working code snippet? I dont need a php-websocket server! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in how you are packing the data. Without knowing which protocol you are trying to use, I can't tell you how to pack it! But, there is a working code snippet in one answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160899/websocket-client-in-php).

Comment: unfortunately these functions are not working. I capture the packets on the Server with wireshark; all available scripts are just making a TCP request, not a HTTP request like the WebSocket class in JavaScript.  I try to build a a script on my own with curl, it connects successfully but I cant Close the Connection by curl_close.