# PHP WebSocket Client Library

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have a WebSocket Server created using Python.

I would like to know whether there is any library which allows me to create a WebSocket Client using PHP 5.3.1 and connect it with the Server I have created?

I have gone through the Symbiose WebSocket client library and Gabrielbull WebSocket Client library but the issue is that the requirement for them is PHP 5.3.9 or greater, but I am using PHP 5.3.1.

Please suggest me with any such library if available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebSocket client in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160899/websocket-client-in-php)