# Unable to connect to websocket using wss:// in php

Tags: php, sockets, http, websocket, get

first of all I want to apologize if there is some mistakes in my post I'm not a native english (french).
So I'm facing a problem trying to connect myself to a websocket with a wss:// domain. The domain is this one : wss://engine.coss.io/api/v1/ws/v1/ht/{ETH_BTC}.
the last part of the URL is a king of query string you can find the detail of this at : https://api.coss.io/v1/spec

First of all I tried to connect to this adresse through chrome but I get the error "ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME" and I found that is was related to some sort of missing certificates.
But my goal was to make it work with php so I tried several ways to connect to this adress but nothing worked this is one of the way I tried to connect to it :

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
echo $socket;
echo socket_connect($socket ,"35.198.217.124",443)?"true":"false";


$in = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$out = '';

echo "Sending HTTP GET request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.\n";

echo "Reading response:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
echo $out;
}
```

Thank you for any help :)
Happy New Year !

EDIT :

After multiples try I get to this situation where I have two pieces of code on getting 200 responce on the root of the machine but definitely not what I want and the second one which get 400 error bad request the two pieces of code are right here :

the 200 response on the root (note that if I add /api to the path I get 404 error):

```
$contextOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

$fp = stream_socket_client("ssl://engine.coss.io:443", $errstr, $errno, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "true\n";

    fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" .
        "Host: www.engine.coss.io\r\n" .
        "Accept: */*\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

And this one gives me a 400 bad Request :

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
echo $socket;
echo socket_connect($socket ,"35.198.217.124",443)?"true":"false";


$in = "GET /api/v1/ws/v1/ht/{ETH_BTC} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: https://www.engine.coss.io\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\n\r\n";
//$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$out = '';

echo "Sending HTTP GET request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.\n";

echo "Reading response:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
echo $out;
}
```

EDIT 2 :

So I email the support of the website they told me that there was a mistake on the URL, the right one is : wss://engine.coss.io/ws/v1/ht/{ETH_BTC}

This seems to work with this code because I get a 101 successful handshake but the problem now is that the script ends once the handshake is successful so I never get the informations I want, maybe there is a way to keep the script listening throught the websocket ? I didn't find anything in the documentation ...

code :

```
$contextOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

$fp =stream_socket_client("ssl://engine.coss.io:443/ws/v1/ht/{COSS_ETH}",$errstr,$errno,30,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,$context);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
echo "true\n";



fwrite($fp, "GET /ws/v1/ht/{COSS_ETH} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: engine.coss.io\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r\n\r\n");
    // Notez que si ici je rajoute au path /api/v1/ws/v1/ht/{ETH_BTC} j'obtiens une erreur 404 not found ...

    while (!feof($fp)) {

        echo fgets($fp, 2024);

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebSocket client in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160899/websocket-client-in-php)

Comment: I saw this post but was not helpfull, because the problem come from the adress, and php 7 have the tools needed to connect to a websocket no need to a library as they say in your post ...

Comment: seeing your question, this is not how the websockets work. perhaps you need to read about [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) first.

Comment: @Binar Web I saw your link but I couldn't learn more about websockets in php, the thing is that I'm close to get the connection because the hanshake is successful but afterwards it closes the connection, I've read a lot in the rfc documentation but nothing helped me if you can i'll be very gratefull

Answer (score 2):

The 'wss://' stream is not supported by PHP by default, but you can implement your own 'wss://' StreamWrapper class.

Here's an example. Changing 'var' into 'wss' in stream_wrapper_register() will get you started.

http://php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php

Here are all the methods you can implement in your StreamWrapper class, but you probably won't need them all.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I will look at your link right after writing my answer. But I was wondering : I got the ip adress of the web socket then I made a line in php : `echo socket_connect($socket ,"35.198.217.124",443)?"true":"non"` and i got true but after when I try to send something to that kind of websocket (with header probably wrong) I got an 400 error 'BAD REQUEST' does that mean that I succeded to connect but I send the wrong request ?

Comment: @CYRUS Yes, that's indeed what it means. You're connecting successfully, but after you're sending a HTTP request to 35.198.217.124, but you're using the wrong domain name www.example.com. That's why it fails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that's obviously true but after multiple try with other host name I still get the bad request response do you have an idea of where the mistake could come from ?

Comment: @CYRUS If you change to socket_connect() line to: echo socket_connect($socket, "93.184.216.34", 80) ? "true" : "false"; it DOES work when using 'Host: www.example.com'. 93.184.216.34 is the IP-address of www.example.com. If your connecting on port 443 you're using HTTPS and you need additional steps to setup a SSL connection. Unfortunately I don't now to setup HTTPS/SSL manually.

Comment: @CYRUS Maybe the following link will help you: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/how-use-ssl-sockets-php

Comment: I edited my post maybe this could give you some idea in making this work ??

Comment: @CYRUS. I've added a new answer. I think this is enough to start using the api.

Answer (score 0):

I've made your second code block working (the one with stream_context_create()).
The code below retrieves the exchange rate between ETH and BTC.
I don't think you need to implement wss:// anymore, because their api seems also be available on https://

```
$contextOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

$fp = stream_socket_client("ssl://engine.coss.io:443", $errstr, $errno, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "true\n";

    fwrite($fp, "GET /api/v1/dp?symbol=ETH_BTC  HTTP/1.1\r\n" .
        "Host: engine.coss.io\r\n" .
        "Accept: */*\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

returns:

```
{"symbol":"ETH_BTC","asks":[["0.03698000","0.12000000"],["0.03705000","0.12000000"],["0.03715000","0.12000000"], .....
```

Comment: Hi @EvE thanks you for your answer, you're right this works perfectly, but the thing is that is this case the request is a regular http request and I would never get informed of the changes on the website until I make a http request.

Furthermore there is a system of units in the website http request cost 1 units where as websocket cost 0 units this is why I wanted to use them, I edited the post I think we are getting closer to the working code :)

Comment: @CYRUS I currently have lack of time to look into it further, but just out of curiosity: How can it be that this site charges 1 units? Because I'm not even and a member of this site and I can also use https:// requests.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using textalk/websocket package.
after installing with composer

```
require("vendor/autoload.php")
use WebSocket\Client;

 $client = new Client("wss://engine.coss.io/api/v1/ws/v1/ht/{ETH_BTC}");
        if(isset($client)){
            while(true){
                try{
                    $message = $client->receive();
                    Log::alert($message);
                }
                catch(ConnectionException $e){
                    Log::error("failed to fetch price updates ".$e->getMessage());
                    break;
                }
               

            }
        }
```